# Batch rename of files including complete parent directory structure

Tags: batch-file, include, parent-child, directory-structure, file-rename

I have quite an extensive folder structure with only one file in the deepest/last folder. File name: model.cgf

What I want is to have a command-line batch-file that renames all files,  renaming them so they list their complete parent folder structure. And then copy all the files into one designated folder.
The copied files would act as a catalog. So I know, when viewing a file, it's exact location in the folder structure. 
It would be awesome if the script could add only newer files when it is run again.

```
    Here is an example of the current file/folder structure:

    _All_Models
    |  |__Script.bat
    |
    |__Catalog
    |
    |__Models
       |
       |__SubFolder
       |  |__model.cfg 
       |  |
       |  |__SubFolder
       |  |  |__model.cfg
       |  |
       |  |__SubFolder
       |     |__SubFolder
       |     |  |__model.cfg
       |     |
       |     |__SubFolder
       |        |__SubFolder
       |           |__SubFolder
       |              |__model.cfg
       |
       |__etc.
       |  |__etc.
       |
       |__etc.
```

Here is an example of what I want:

```
    _All_Models
    |  |__Script.bat
    |
    |__Catalog
    |  |__SubFolder.cfg 
    |  |__SubFolder_SubFolder.cfg
    |  |__SubFolder_SubFolder_SubFolder.cfg
    |  |__SubFolder_SubFolder.cfg
    |  |__SubFolder_SubFolder_SubFolder_SubFolder.cfg
    |  |__etc.
    |  |__etc.
    |  |__etc.
    |
    |__Models
       |__etc.
       |__etc.
       |__etc.
```

What I can currently do is batch rename the file "model.cfg" into "parent-folder.cfg" and copy it into a designated folder. This will rename and consolidate all files, however I now am missing all previous parent folders and dont know where in the folder-structure the file is located.

I know very little about scripting, so I have done many searches to find something useful, but perhaps what I want is not possible.
This is what I came-up with:

```
    CD Models

    REM Rename
    for /r %%D in (.) do (for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /A:-D "%%D"') do echo "%%D\%%F" "%%~nxD%%~xF")
    for /r %%F in (*) do (for /f "delims=" %%D in ("%%~dpF.") do ren "%%F" "%%~nxD%%~xF")

    REM Copy
    for /r "F:\All_Models\Models" %%i in (*.cgf) do copy "%%i" "F:\All_Models\Catalog"
```

My Catalog folder will now list all files named as: SubFolder.cgf (which is not detailed enough)
The script also changes all filenames in the original folders, these should still be named: model.cgf

I'd appreciate any help on improving my script :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had already started creating a script before I saw Magoo's answer.

My answer is almost the same, except:

- All path computations are relative to the location of the script, so no need to set source or destination directories
- I eliminate the leading path prefix differently. My method will fail if the leading path contains the `=` character (unlikely a problem)
- I copy the files instead of move, which I believe is the intent of the OP
- I hide the result of the copy and ECHO the resultant name of the copied file
- I transfer all needed paths to variables and then toggle delayed expansion on and off so as to protect any `!` that may be present in any of the paths.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%F in (
  'dir /b /s "%~dp0Models\Model.cfg"'
) do (
  set "old=%%F"
  set "new=%%~pF"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  set "new=!new:%~p0Models\=!"
  set "new=!new:\=_!"
  set "new=!new:~0,-1!.cfg"
  echo !new!
  copy "!old!" "%~dp0Catalog\!new!" >nul
  endlocal
)
```

I did not bother trying to only copy new files. Existing files in the catalog are simply overwritten. To properly determine if the file has changed you would need to use `FC`, which seems like a waste of time and effort.

Comment: This also does the job :)
Using this script because of the copy/move thingie.
Thanks ALOT!

Comment: @Freyr, then you should perhaps [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) this answer; please learn what to do when [someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)...

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /s /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\models\model.cfg" '
 ) DO (
  SET "destination=%%~dpa"
  SET "destination=!destination:*\models\=!"
  SET "destination=!destination:\=_!"
 ECHO MOVE "%%a" "%sourcedir%\catalog\!destination:~0,-1!.cfg"
)
GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances. The listing uses a setting that suits my system.

The `for` loop delivers each `model.cfg` file-location to `%%a` in turn. The drive and path are assigned to `destination`, then the part up to `models\` is replaced by *nothing* and the backslashes are transformed to underscores. Then build the actual destination, remembering that `~dp` includes a final backslash (which is now an underscore) so remove it using the `0,-1` substring.

Note that this uses delayedexpansion, so be prepared for fun and games should the tree contain directories including `!` in addition to the usual suspects.

The required MOVE commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO MOVE` to `MOVE` to actually move the files.  Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file moved`)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%I in ("%~dp0..\Models") do set "ModelsPath=%%~fI\"
for %%I in ("%~dp0..\Catalog") do set "CatalogPath=%%~fI"

for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "%ModelsPath%model.cfg" /A-D /B /S 2^>nul') do (
    set "FilePath=%%~dpI"
    set "FilePath=!FilePath:~0,-1!"
    set "NewFileName=!FilePath:%ModelsPath%=!"
    set "NewFileName=!NewFileName:\=_!%%~xI"
    ren "%%I" "!NewFileName!"
    if exist "%%~dpI!NewFileName!" (
        %SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe "!FilePath!" "%CatalogPath%" "!NewFileName!" /XO /R:3 /W:5 /NS /NC /NFL /NDL /NP /NJH /NJS >nul
        if not errorlevel 1 echo Ignored older "%%I"
        ren "%%~dpI!NewFileName!" "%%~nxI"
    ) else echo Failed to rename "%%I"
)

endlocal
```

This batch file works only if no folder or file name contains `!` and folder path of `Models` folder does not contain anywhere `=`.

The batch file first determines absolute path to the directories `Catalog` and `Models` from batch file path. Please note that environment variable `ModelsPath` holds the absolute path of folder `Models` with a backslash at end while `CatalogPath` is without backslash at end.

Then command **FOR** with option `/F` runs in a separate command process started with `%ComSpec% /c` and the command line specified within `'`...`'` as additional arguments in background the command **DIR**. So executed is with `C:\Windows` being the Windows directory and `C:\Temp\Models\` being assigned to `ModelsPath`:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c dir "C:\Temp\Models\model.cfg" /A-D /B /S 2>nul
```

**DIR** searches in

- folder `C:\Temp\Models`
- and all its subfolders because of option `/S`
- for files with name `model.cfg` with
- excluding directories because of `/A-D` which by chance are also named `model.cfg`
- and output the found files with just full qualified file name, i.e. path + file name + file extension, because of options `/B` and `/S`.

This output by **DIR** to handle **STDOUT** of started command process is captured by **FOR** and processed line by line after started `cmd.exe` terminated itself.

Read the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

The **FOR** option `delims=` disables line splitting behavior of **FOR** to get every full qualified file name always assigned completely to specified loop variable `I`.

First the file path of current `model.cfg` is determined without backslash at end.

Then then `Models` path (with backslash at end) at beginning is removed and remaining path is assigned to environment variable `NewFileName`. Next all backslashes in this remaining path are replaced by an underscore.

The current `model.cfg` is renamed to new file name before **ROBOCOPY** is used to copy this file with its new file name to folder `Catalog` if the source file does not already exist in destination folder or the source file is newer than the file with same name in destination folder.

A file cannot be renamed if it is opened by an application with file sharing permissions set to deny renaming of file while being opened by the application. This is the reason for the additional **IF** condition.

Last the current `model.cfg` is renamed back to this file name in its source folder.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `dir /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `ren /?`
- `robocopy /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

See also on SS64:

- [ROBOCOPY](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)
- [ROBOCOPY Exit Codes](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy-exit.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible way:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_SOURCE=%~dp0Models"
set "_TARGET=%~dp0Catalog"
set "_MASK=model*.cfg"
set "_CHAR=_"

rem // Change into source directory:
pushd "%_SOURCE%" && (
    rem /* List matching files by `xcopy /L` and
    rem    capture the result by `for /F`: */
    for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%F in ('
        xcopy /L /S /I "%_MASK%" "%TEMP%"
    ') do (
        rem // Store relative path of currently iterated item:
        set "ITEM=%%F"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        rem // Split off file name from relative path:
        set "PAR=!ITEM!|" & set "PAR=!PAR:\%%~nxF|=!"
        rem // Build new name and process current item:
        copy /Y "!ITEM!" "!_TARGET!\!PAR:\=%_CHAR%!%%~xF"
        endlocal
    )
    popd
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

This approach makes use of the fact that [`xcopy`](https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) returns the source paths relative to the root, `/S` recurses sub-directories and `/L` prevents copying but just lists files that would be copied without. A [`for /F` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) captures that list of relative paths, gets the parent directories, replaces every path separator `\` by `_` to build the target file names and then copies each file to the destination. Already existing files become overwritten without prompt; to confirm instead, just replace `/Y` by `/-Y`. To move files instead of copying, replace `copy` by `move`, of course.